# Architecture of inheritances with all parameter combinations

Tags: java, inheritance, architecture, combinations

i have a question regarding architecture/functionality:

Lets say for a given problem I have an algorithm that solves the problem. It can use a certain amount of information, represented by an object containing some instance variables of generic types. In fact there are n variables that are relevant but the algorithm may solve the problem with an unknown subset. To find that subset I want to be able to pass every possible combination of variables to the algorithm. So I want a structure that allows me to switch between the information types with as little effort as possible.

Especially two information objects should be equal when only the currently investigated subset of variables are equal. So it seems i need to overwrite equals. This would mean to write a class for every possible subset, leading to 2^n classes total.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? And if it has to be the 2^n classes, how would you design the inheritances?

---

In response to Andy Turners and mellowmaroons comment: I imagine the solver to be a function f : S -> {0,1} that tells me the correct action (0 or 1) for a given status s. The status s is given by a vector of length k. To keep it easy just assume S = Z^k, e.g. Integers. But it may be enough to build the status room with an unknown subset of variables, leading to S = Z^l , l < k. In order to test the possible subsets I need to let the algorithm run with objects of the corresponding status room, respectively. So during the process, objects of the status room will be generated and passed to the solver object. The solver should be able to accept them and he must be able to recognize a status that exists already.
Generally asked, what is the way to structure this?

---

Here's an example of my current approach

```
//abstract superclass to wrap the information types

   public abstract class Information {

   }

// concrete class that contains 1st and 2nd parameters

    public class InformationA extends Information{

        int size;
        int weight;

    // two InformationA objects are equal if only 1st and 2nd parameter are equal

    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o instanceof InformationA){
           InformationA info = (InformationA) o;
           return info.size == size && info.weight == weight;
        }
        return false
    }

// concrete class that contains 2nd and 3rd Parameters

    public class InformationB extends Information {

       int weight;
       int color;

       //another equals method with the same structure than before

   }

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

// the solver class contains the solve function
// It associates an action with every possible status/information

public class Solver {

    HashMap<Information, Boolean> solveFunction;

    // If a status/information has been treated already return the value
    // else generate a random value

    public Boolean getAction(Information i){
        if(solveFunction.containsKey(i)) return solveFunction.get(i);
        solveFunction.put(i, new Random().nextInt(2) == 0);
        return solveFunction.get(i);
    }

    public void solve(Problem problem){
//      while(!problem.isSolved()){
//##        somehow extract only the needed status Parameters 
//          pass them to getAction method and invoke the response on the problem
//      }
    }

}

public class Problem {

//    public boolean isSolved(){
//        return some signal
//    }

//   public void process(Boolean action){
//        the process develops according to the action and reaches a new state   
//      }

//## public getStatus(){
//       return the status in a way that the solver can extract the needed subset of information
//   }

}

public class Controller {

//  generate the problem and the solver
//##somehow tell the solver which Information type to use
//  Let the solver solve the problem    

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Problem problem = new Problem();
        new Solver().solve(problem);
    }

}
```

It's obvious that this approach leads to the problem of generating the required subset and passing it to solver. This might be solvable. But still there is the problem of writing all the Information classes with the different parameter combinations.

Comment: Why do you think that inheritance is the correct way to model all the combinations? If you have a generic solver, you need a type that will function generically; you can't do it unless all of these "parameter types" have a common interface.

Comment: I think you should clarify what exactly it is you're asking.  Also, object-ortented concepts aren't limited only to Java, you may want to revise your tags if your question pertains to OOP as a whole.

Comment: Do you have a code sample that would show two different subset classes with your current implementation idea? The problem is a bit too generically described and lacks real-world details.

Answer (score 0):

Well that question is pretty old. I think I made some progress in solving it, though, so I'm posting my approach, hoping for some feedback or improvement.

In order to switch between different Parameter combinations I tried to use subclasses of a superclass "Information". Instead, I now use a HashMap to represent one instance of an Information class and a HashMap of those HashMaps represents the function f that assign an Action to every Information instance.

```
// the class that represents first parameter

public class A{
     //can be a selfmade class or a String or some generic type
}

// same for parameters B,C,D,E...

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

// the solver class fills the solveFunction HashMap
// It associates an action with every possible status/information

public class Solver {

    HashMap<HashMap<String,Object>, Boolean> solveFunction;

    // If a status/information has been treated already return the value
    // else generate a random value

    public Boolean getAction(HashMap<String, Object> info){
        if(solveFunction.containsKey(info)) return solveFunction.get(info);
        solveFunction.put(info, new Random().nextInt(2) == 0);
        return solveFunction.get(info);
    }

    public HashMap<HashMap<String, Object>, Boolean> solve(Problem problem, HashMap<HashMap<String, Object>, Boolean> solveFunction){
        this.solveFunction = solveFunction;
        while(!problem.isSolved()){
            problem.process(getAction(problem.getStatus()));
        }
    }

}

public class Problem {

String[] usedParameters;

public Problem(String[] usedParameters){
    this.usedParameters = usedParameters;
}

    public boolean isSolved(){
//        return a signal
    }

   public void process(Boolean action){
//        the process develops according to the action and reaches a new state   
      }

 public getStatus(){
    HashMap<String, Object> status = new HashMap();
    for(String s : usedParameters){
        switch(s){
            case "A": status.add("A", new Object());
            case "B": status.add("B", new Object());
            case "C": status.add("C", new Object());
// and so on
        }
    }
    return status;
}
}

public class Controller {

//  generate the problem and the solver
//  Let the solver solve the problem    

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] usedParameters = {"A","C"};
        HashMap<HashMap<String, Object>, Boolean> solveFunction = new HashMap();
        Problem problem = new Problem(usedParameters);
        new Solver().solve(problem, solveFunction);
    }

}
```

The above code is of course not working but should only give the idea. 
The case that the randomly generated solvefunction fails must be catched. I think the rest of the code can't be completed without losing generality.